# Noise Detection in audio signal

Tags: signal-processing

I have a 1 min clip of audio signal sampled at 44.1KHz.
The spectrogram of the same is provided below.
[image]

There is too much of background noise in the clip

The link to the original clip is provided
[here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/150037997/Share/cpp_part.wav)

What will be the best possible way to either a) Reduce the background noise or b) Enhance the speech signals only.

Also, how can the noise be identified in the spectrogram?
For generating spectrogram I have used the following commands

```
[x, Fs] = wavread('cpp_part.wav');
spectrogram(x,512,400,512,Fs,'yaxis');
```

Comment: You see those stripes at [0.4, 0.8, 1.2, 1.5] x 10^4 Hz?  This appears to be a 8 kHz-sampled signal that has been upsampled to 40 kHz by simply inserting 4 zero-samples after every nonzero sample, causing a wild amount of aliasing. (It appears it was then further resampled to 44.1 kHz with conventional anti-aliasing).  You might as well low-pass filter it to remove energy above 4 kHz.  It will sound more muffled, and will still have background noise, but at least it won't sound aliased.

Comment: dpwe's observations are totally correct. However, what you're really asking is "what is the state of the art in speech reconstruction", and that is a question that has been discussed in hundreds of books; it's just too broad.